# firebase messaging onCreate not called

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm facing an issue with FirebaseMessaging class.

```
public class FirebaseService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = FirebaseService.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        GlobalApp.logDebug(TAG, "Firebase Service started");
    }
}
```

The onCreate is not called.
I don't receive any notifications

I'm using `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.2.0'`

The google documentation is not clear when that service starts.

This is my manifest :

```
<service
            android:name=".common.google.FirebaseService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false"
            android:directBootAware="true">
            <intent-filter android:priority="-500">
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: What's the purpose of `android:priority="-500"` ?

Comment: Thanks, I tried to remove that and it worked ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @azizbekian

```
<service
            android:name=".common.google.FirebaseService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="false"
            android:stopWithTask="false"
            android:directBootAware="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
```

I just had to remove the `android:priority="-500"`...

Facepalm..